# I get a KeyError when searching for a label that does not exist in a pandas.Series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have pandas.Series called `cluster_size` that has labels and a count. Something like the following:

```
Label
0      3
1     15
2     15
3     18
-1     3
```

This is constantly changing in a way that the label -1 might not always exist.
If the label does not exist i get the following error:

`KeyError: 'the label [-1] is not in the [index]'`

So what I want to do is to check if this label actually exists or not.

I have tried the following but this does not seem to help since I continue to get the same error.

```
if cluster_size.loc[-1] is None:
    print("the label does not exist")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `try-except` statement:

```
try:
    idx = cluster_size.loc[-1]
except KeyError:
     print("the label does not exist")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if -1 not in df.index:
    print("the label does not exist")
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! this actually works but the `try-except` method as proposed in another answer seems more safe :/